# Плавный кроссбраузерный скролл страницы. jQuery || Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как реализовать плавный скроллинг страницы ? Кто знает, можно на чистом js. Или же jQuery.

Comment: Интересно почему минусы

Comment: @midia видал я такие "плавные скроллы" - сразу хотелось руки поотрывать тому, кто это делал. P.S. Я не минусовал, но ответ на этот вопрос ищется за 5 минут.

Comment: Пишите более развёрнутые вопросы - минусов будет меньше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианты на чистом js:

### Есть очень удобный способ проскролить к элементу:

```
el.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth', // для плавности
  block: 'start'
})
```

Но насколько я понял у него не такая хорошя поддержка как у вариантов ниже (плохая поддержка именно первого аргумента `scrollIntoViewOptions`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее о методе.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

---

### Если надо чтобы элемент оказался в вверху:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#element')
const top = element.getBoundingClientRect().top

window.scrollTo({
  top, // скрол так чтобы элемент оказался в верху страницы
  behavior: 'smooth' // чтобы было плавным
})
```

[Демонстрирующий пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/Oopwpp)

---

### Если надо чтобы элемент оказался в центре:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#element')
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
const viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)

window.scroll({
  top: rect.top + rect.height / 2 - viewHeight / 2,
  behavior: 'smooth' // чтобы было плавным
});
```

[Демонстрирующий пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/MqpBOq)

---

### На нужное количество пикселей вниз:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 200, // на 200px от верха
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

---

**Поддержка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишут что `scroll` это тот же метод что и `scrollTo` но поддержку показывает лучше у `scrollTo`.

[Подробнее о методе.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: Очень благодарен за развернутый ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такое

```js
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

var goUp = true;
var end = null;
var interval = null;

function handle(delta) {
  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
  var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

  if (end == null) {
    end = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
  end -= 20 * delta;
  goUp = delta > 0;

  if (interval == null) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
      if (scrollTop <= 0 ||
        scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
        goUp && step > -1 ||
        !goUp && step < 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        end = null;
      }
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step);
    }, animationInterval);
  }
}
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.block2 {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```